# jOOQ select Master-Details filter by details's property

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, jooq, r2dbc

Currently I am using the latest jOOQ 3.19.5(R2dbc/Postgres) in my project.

I encountered an issue like this.

Given `master` and details` table.

```bash
|master |
id, 
type 

|details| 
id, 
master_id, 
other_id // connect other tables.
```

I want to query master and details together with the following condition from external parameters:

- master type
- details other_id

I tried to use the following query clause:

```kotlin
dslContext
  .select(
  master.id, 
  ...other master fields, 
  multiple(
    select(details.id, details.other_id)
      .from(details)
      .where(details.master_id.eq(masters.id).and(details.other_id.eq(other_id_param))
  )
)
  .from(master)
  .where(master.type.eq(type_param))
```

But this query will includes all masters that type is `type_param` with some empty details.

I try to add a `count` subselect clause as field to filter out result like this.

```kotlin
dslContext
  .select(
  master.id, 
  ...other master fields, 
  multiple(
    select(details.id, details.other_id)
      .from(details)
      .where(details.master_id.eq(masters.id).and(details.other_id.eq(other_id_param))
   ),
  select(field("count(*)", BIGINT))
      .from(details)
      .where(details.master_id.eq(masters.id).and(details.other_id.eq(other_id_param))
     .asField<Long>("details_count")
)
  .from(master)
  .where(master.type.eq(type_param).and(field("details_count").greaterThat(0)))
```

It doesn't work, and report error in the generated SQL:

```bash
 column "details_count" does not exist
```

When I added an `exists` to where, it works.

```kotlin
dslContext
  .select(
    master.id, 
    ...other master fields, 
    multiple(
      select(details.id, details.other_id)
        .from(details)
        .where(details.master_id.eq(masters.id)
          .and(details.other_id.eq(other_id_param))
     )
  )
  .from(master)
  .where(master.type.eq(type_param)
    .andExists(  
      selectOne()
        .from(details)      
        .where(details.master_id.eq(masters.id)
         .and(details.other_id.eq(other_id_param))
      )
```

Is there a better SQL to select the `master/details` in one query and filter by the `detail`'s property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot filter anything using `WHERE` that you've projected in the `SELECT` clause due to the [logical order of operations in SQL](https://blog.jooq.org/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/).

In order to make your `COUNT(*)` value available to your `WHERE` clause, you have to push it into the `FROM` clause, e.g. by using a [derived table](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/derived-tables/), or by using [`LATERAL`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/joined-tables/join-mode-lateral/) -
in your particular case it would work. I've described this technique also here, [where `LATERAL` is used to create "local column variables" in SQL](https://blog.jooq.org/lateral-is-your-friend-to-create-local-column-variables-in-sql/)

E.g. this could work:

```kotlin
// Create a derived table
val t = 
  select(count())
  .from(details)
  .where(details.master_id.eq(master.id))
  .and(details.other_id.eq(other_id_param))
  .asTable("t", "c")

// Dereference the count column from it
val c = t.field("c", INTEGER);

dslContext
  .select(
    master.id, 
    // ...other master fields, 
    multiset(
      select(details.id, details.other_id)
      .from(details)
      .where(details.master_id.eq(master.id))
      .and(details.other_id.eq(other_id_param))),

    // Project the count
    c
  )
  .from(master)

  // Lateral join it
  .crossJoin(lateral(t))

  // Reference the count in WHERE
  .where(master.type.eq(type_param).and(c.gt(0)))
```

Note though that your [`EXISTS` approach will certainly outperform any `COUNT(*) > 0` approach](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/reference/dont-do-this/dont-do-this-count-instead-of-exists/) as also recommended by jOOQ (if you don't really need to project the exact count value).